# How to convert big number to normal number?

Tags: solidity, javascript, bignumber

I am new to testing and I want to know how to convert a big number to a real number.

I use bignumber in the following command:

```
console.log(await this.crowdsale.rate());
```

This is what gets printed in the terminal:

```
BigNumber { s: 1, e: 2, c: [ 500 ] }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what you mean by real number. You can check out [here](https://etherconventer.online) the divisions used in Ethereum.

For wei:

```
let bigNo = await this.crowdsale.rate();
console.log(bigNo.toNumber());
```

For ether add this:

```
console.log(web3.fromWei(bigNo.toNumber()));
```

If you're using version ^1.0.0 of web3, use `web3.utils.fromWei` instead of `web3.fromWei`.

Comment: thanks paul .i forgot about toNumber() thanks for reminding me about it .

Answer (score 3):

Not every `BigNumber` can be converted into a Javascript `Number` with an **equivalent value**.

If that had been the case, then we wouldn't have needed a `BigNumber` class to begin with.

Referring to your actual question - you haven't really explained why you need to perform this conversion.

Your question implies that you don't like the printout, in which case you can fix your code as follows:

```
let rate = await this.crowdsale.rate();
console.log(rate.toFixed());
```

If you're interested in performing additional calculations, then you can simply use [`BigNumber` functions](https://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/).

So technically speaking, there shouldn't be any need convert your `BigNumber` into a Javascript `Number`.